# Prevent users from banning themselves and show a error discord.py

Tags: python, discord

So, I am trying to make a ban command, the ban command works good, but the only thing wrong is that users can ban themselves, here is my code.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.channel.send('error message')
    return
    if ctx.author.id == member.id:
        await ctx.channel.send("nope")
        return
  message = f"You have been banned on {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
  try:
    await member.send(message)
  except:
    return
```

Everything else on this works great, but not the part that would check if the user mentioned is the author. It will still send a DM saying they have been banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have an indentation error as your check for if the member == author only occurs after a return.

Updated code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
  if member == None:
    await ctx.channel.send('error message')
    return
  if ctx.author.id == member.id: # <-- Unindent this section
    await ctx.channel.send("nope")
    return
  message = f"You have been banned on {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
  try:
    await member.send(message)
  except:
    return
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't notice this little thing haha, you're a lifesaver